# Issues with declining meeting invites for others

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I have two related questions regarding Outlook invites.  First, if Admin A has permission to send out invites for Boss B, who does it show the invite is from? A on behalf of B?  Or just B?  Does it matter if it's sent directly from B's calendar?  Or will the same information be on the invite?

Secondly, if an invitee C declines an invite, will they no longer be able to receive emails sent out from the "Contact Attendees" function?

Thank you.

Comment: It would only take a couple of minutes for you to do some science and test this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Re Q1: It depends on which permission Admin A has on Boss B's mailbox. If you don't won't to see "on behalf of", you will need to have Send As permission. Otherwise, you will see "on behalf of".

Re Q2: Based on my testing, invitee C will still be involved in the To/Cc address when using the "Contact Attendees" function.